# SQL % increased over time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope someone can help. I am using SQL Server 2016 and I have data that looks like the below;

```
OrderID    Value        SubscriptionLengthInMonths  SubscriptionStart   SubscriptionEnd   Renew
2344        1920                       24                   14/05/2018   14/05/2020          1
2555        5376                       12                   01/03/2018   01/03/2019          1
```

What I need is the monthly payment value adding as a column, broken down by year. We work out the monthly value by dividing SubscriptionValue by SubscriptionLengthInMonths.

What makes it tricky is sometimes there is a flag on my data (autorenew) which means if the value is 1, the subscription will renew automatically on the SubscriptionEnd, for the same period of months as the original subscription. When this happens, a 2% increase is added to the monthly fee. I need columns that show the monthly fee of each subscription, broken down by year. An ideal output of the above example would look like the below

```
OrderID SubscriptionValue   SubscriptionLengthInMonths  2018    2019    2020    2021
2344       1920                         24               80      80     81.6    81.6
2555       5376                         12               448    456.96  466.06  475.36
```

The reason the OrderID 2344 payment is 80 in both 2018 and 2019 is because this is a 2 year (24 month) subscription which doesn't auto renew until 2020. This renews again in 2020 (which reflects in the below as the % has been added on for 2020 and 2021)

OrderID 2555 renews every 12 months which is why the % increase is applied across all years.

I understand this is complex, just hoping someone can show me how to achieve this. Thanks, Jess

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the example data is what the table looks like, along with an additional autorenew flag

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the monthly amount incremented by 2.0 for each subscription period.

The arithmetic logic is something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (power(1.02,
              datediff(month, subscriptionStart, '2018-12-31') / SubscriptionLengthInMonths
             ) * (SubscriptionValue / SubscriptionLengthInMonths)
       ) monthly_2018,
       (power(1.02,
              datediff(month, subscriptionStart, '2019-12-31') / SubscriptionLengthInMonths
             ) * (SubscriptionValue / SubscriptionLengthInMonths)
       ) monthly_2019,
       . . .
from t;
```

This should work for your data.  I'm not sure how the autorenew logic comes into play.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I needed. I was going about it the total wrong way (using case statements)